# Using foldr and bind to terminate on nothing

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So, essentially I have some monadic function wrapped in a `MaybeT` I want to use `Nothing` as the terminating case for a recursion

My understanding of `foldr` is that if it can produce the result without consuming the entire list, it can be used on an infinite list safely i.e. `foldr (&&) True $ repeat False` is still able to return `False`.

At the moment I have:

```
repeaterM a f = foldr (=<<) (return a) $ repeat f
```

This type checks, but doesn't actually work. Could anyone explain to me why I can't use this function to repeatedly apply a function to its own result until it returns `Nothing`?

Comment: Why not `go a f = f a >>= \a' -> go a' f`?

Comment: Could even make it `go f a = f a >>= go f` to get rid of the lambda . That does seem to work and seems a bit more elegant than what I was doing. I was originally generalising this from a function that would only do the action n times, using a list, hence the fold. Still, I'd like to know why this function doesn't work .

Comment: What you need is actually [iterateM_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:iterateM_)

Comment: tl;dr `Maybe`'s `=<<` is strict on its RHS so `foldr (=<<)` on an infinite list never terminates.

Answer (score 4):

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

So

```
foldr (&&) True $ repeat False
   = go (repeat False) where go [] = True ; go (y:ys) = y && go ys
   = False && go (repeat False) where go [] = True ; go (y:ys) = y && go ys
   = False
```

as you expect.

But

```
foldr (=<<) (return a) $ repeat f
   = go (repeat f) where go [] = return a ; go (y:ys) = y =<< ys
   = f =<< go (repeat f) where go [] = return a ; go (y:ys) = y =<< ys
   = f =<< f =<< go (repeat f) where go [] = return a ; go (y:ys) = y =<< ys
   = f =<< f =<< f =<< go (repeat f) where go [] = return a ; go (y:ys) = y =<< ys
   ...
```

What you're doing here is *not* repeatedly applying a function to its own result until it returns `Nothing`.

You are building up the computation from its end: the RHS of each `=<<` must be computed before the LHS can be carried out. But you have an infinite list, so you never get to the start of the computation.

You might try to define

```
repeaterM a f = foldl (>>=) (return a) $ repeat f
```

instead. This won't work either (thanks is7s).

Comment: `foldl` never terminates on infinite lists.

Comment: Aha, now I understand. I was confusing myself in how the computation was actually being built up. I had an inkling that it was something along these lines, but I couldn't quite work it out in my head.  Thanks!